# Thread.Sleep и нажатие клавиши в консоли

Tags: c#

Условно... Нужно написать программу для консоли, которая будет показывать числа от 1 до 8 и показывало некоторое время, то есть Thread.Sleep(100) условно.. Но только если клавиша зажата. Недостаток в том, что пока программа "спит" 100 миллисекунд консоль продолжает получать нажатия. И если отпустить клавишу, то программа все равно будет и дальше показывать числа... Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы программа начинала показывать числа с Ожиданием и сразу же прекращала при отпускании клавиши?

На самом деле у меня поехала крыша и я хочу сделать игру в консоли, не спрашивайте зачем :D, но вот что пока вышло сделать (сори, если там где-то криво, я в первый раз пользуюсь сайтом. Но надеюсь, вы поймете суть кода...)

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 using System.Threading;

 namespace ConsoleApp6
 {
    class Program
    {
        static public void Frame_Show(int n)
        {
            if (n == 1)
            {
               Frame_1(1);
            }

            if (n == 2)
            {
                Frame_2(1);
            }

            if (n == 3)
            {
                Frame_3(1);
            }

            if (n == 4)
            {
                Frame_4(1);
            }

            if (n == 5)
            {
                Frame_5(1);
            }

            if (n == 6)
            {
                Frame_6(1);
            }

            if (n == 7)
            {
                Frame_7(1);
            }

            if (n == 8)
            {
                Frame_8(1);
            }

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.Clear();

    }

    static public void Frame_1(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write("1");
    }

    static public void Frame_2(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write("2");
    }

    static public void Frame_3(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.Write("3");
    }

    static public void Frame_4(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.Write("4");
    }

    static public void Frame_5(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.Write("5");
    }

    static public void Frame_6(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.Write("6");
    }

    static public void Frame_6(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.Write("6");
    }

    static public void Frame_7(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.Write("7");
    }

    static public void Frame_8(int n)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
        Console.Write("8");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 1;
        Console.SetWindowSize(80, 30);
        Console.SetBufferSize(80, 30);
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        ConsoleKey key;
        while (1 > 0)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    Frame_Show(n);
                    n++;
                    if (n == 9)
                    {
                        n = 1;
                    }

                }
            }
            
        }

        
        

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так может сработать.

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    while (Console.KeyAvailable)
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.Write(i);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: вроде сработало, попробую для своих целей использовать, спасибо

Comment: а можно ли это улучшить так, чтобы если нажали клавишу, то цифры бы выводились. А если клавиша не нажата, то оставалась определенная цифра, условно 0 ?

Comment: @DmitriyDobr `if (!Console.KeyAvailable) Console.Write(0); else while ...`

Comment: добрый человек, спасибо огромное. Если игра доживет до выхода, можно будет тебя указать в титрах?

Comment: @DmitriyDobr это же просто должно было быть. )

Comment: мои способы не работали)) а ваш работает, хотя там и есть один неисправимый баг, который трудно описать, но причина его появления ясна... как то так...

Comment: а можно с тобой связаться через ЛС? Вк там или инста? Просто там проблема, которую трудно описать вот так вот просто возникла

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос, опишите в нем максимум деталей, вставьте код, и если потребуется, то скриншоты, вставьте так же текст ошибки и укажите, как вы пытались решить вопрос. Если вопрос не об ошибке, а о поведении приложения, то опишите фактическое и ожидаемое поведение. Попробуем разобраться.

Comment: вот, вроде вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271496/Проблема-с-нажатиями-клавиш-в-консоли-c