# странное поведение при долгом зажатии клавиши в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Вообщем, дело такое: пишу игру в консоли и там вроде бы все нормально происходит, при нажатии клавиши игрок передвигается со сменой кадров, при отжатии стоит с кадром стояния. Но происходит странная вещь: когда я нажимаю и удерживаю кнопку, то происходит вот что: игрок перемещается, затем застывает, а потом начинает спокойно перемещаться, пока я клавишу не отожму соре за качество

[image: вот как это выглядит]

Так вот, я подумал, что это у меня какие-то проблемы в цикле. Решил наклипать более простой проект с одним персонажем-символом нуля, который тоже перемещается влево и вправо. Вот сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Threading;

namespace test
{
    class player
    {
        public int x = 1;
        public int previousX = 1;
        public void SetPosition()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(previousX, 5);
            Console.Write(' ');
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 5);
            Console.Write('0');
            previousX = x;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            player p1 = new player();
            p1.x = 1;
            p1.previousX = 1;

            while (true)
            {
                p1.SetPosition();

                while (Console.KeyAvailable == false) { }
                if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
                    p1.x = ChangePlayerPossition(Console.ReadKey(true).Key, p1.x);
            }
        }

        // Изменение координат
        static int ChangePlayerPossition(ConsoleKey key, int x)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    if (x - 1 > 5) { x--; }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    if (x + 1 < 70) { x++; }
                    break;
            }

            return x;
        } 

    

    }
}
```

Может выглядит криво, не спорю. Я думал, что тут этой штуки не будет. Как бы не так

[image: вот как это тут работает]

игрок передвигается на 1 позицию вперед, застывает, а потом начинает двигаться, пока не отожму клавишу...

Может тут дело в реализации и нужно в потоки лезть? Или тут уже ничего не поможет? Вам лично было бы нормально играть в игру с такой темой (как на первой гифке? (тип, может так оставить? :D))

Comment: Просто ремарка про `while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)`. Я же вроде вам писал [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1270771/373567). Надо писать `while (!Console.KeyAvailable)`, то же самое про `if (Console.KeyAvailable)`. А то вы пишете что-то типа `while (true == true)`, когда можно писать просто `while (true)`.

Comment: Видимо у вас в коде отрисовка идёт только при нажатии клавиши, а нужно делать не так.

Comment: видимо придется изучать потоки

Comment: @aepot а как это реализовать? Я просто пытался, но чето не то выходит... Тип, там главный поток считывает нажата ли кнопка. Если нажата, то мы запускаем поток с повторением кадров, а если отжата, то ставим его на паузу?

Comment: Как это реализовать, я уже вам говорил и ссылку на решение давал.